# Where to start learning PHP the professional way?

Tags: php, ide

Since I have heared a lot of how bad some PHP programmer at coding their projects, I feel now that I do not trust resources that I should learn PHP from. Even with books, you find some bad reviews that say that the writer does not follow a good practice and so on. I assume that there is at least some professsional PHP progammers here and would like to ask them where can I start the right way, I mean by the right way to learn the best way and not following bad habits?

- Is there paid online videos for beginner from a prfoessional (not from progammers who follow bad practice) in its field? Except Zend videos which are too expensive!
- What is the most gentle book out there which learn the starters from the beginning the good way in PHP programming?
- What is the most stable IDE for PHP, I mean by this the IDE that have a long history and still keep updating, not an IDE that you can't trust if it will continue or may disappear at any time?

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599212/professional-path-for-beginner-programmer

Comment: get books about patterns and practises which are language independent. Look at books from martin fowler.

Comment: Learn a few other languages first. Then find a PHP reference and read through it.

Comment: Why learning a few other languages first?

Comment: **Practice is the path to proficiency.** But since you are already around, you should browse through old questions once per day. But take recurring advises with a grain of salt; there's a lot of cargo cult programmers on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to define what professional means to you?

Do you consider "professional way" only from people who do php for living, or those who simply have learned php and gets some jobs online as freelancers, or people who knows how to follow good programming practice (patterns, clean code, do more with less code,...) or....

Problem is that you can combine all of those choices and you want get any near to your question which is: **How can you learn php "the right way", with least effort and optimal success, right?**

1. **books** - there is no wrong way of learning (ok, maybe a little), thats simply a process (that takes time), and when you say that some people say that some authors don't follow the "good practice" that doesn't mean that you cant learn from these books, and who says that they know what is good practice. Can they define it? Because we are talking here about beginners level, I presume. And silly as it sounds, when you find that kind off example its also way of learning (you learn on somebody's mistakes)
2. **tutorials** - there are plenty of tutorials from people who are well known in php community, so try to find them (tutorials not people :-), look at php forums, good php web sites.
3. **podcasts** - Try with podcasts ("DPC radio" for example gives you sessions from php conferences and slides, "Lately in php" is also good source of informations, "Software engineering podcast" and "Floss Weekly" are not related to php but will give you knowledge of various open source subjects, techniques, practices, interviews with well known software developers,...)
4. **videos** - "Lynda.com-PHP with MySQL Essential Training" and "Lynda.com-PHP with MySQL Beyond the Basics" are excellent videos for beginners and those who want to learn php from video tutorials.
5. Learn the basics first and then think about good practice (it comes with experience also). By the time you get good grasp on basic stuff you will take some framework and your learning will start to go in different direction.
6. > **Use php manual as your reference, or at least try to teach yourself to use
   >   php manual !!!**

AND Finally: Find some simple example application and start from scratch.

**IDEs** - NetBeans, Aptana, Eclipse,... all free and good.

Comment: +1, DPC radio seems to be really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a visual learner and [Nettuts.com](http://Nettuts.com) have some of the best video tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Just practice practice, read tutorials found with Google. If you don't understand something just search for it till you understand it ;) Also having contact with other PHP-developers is handy to ask things quickly. This way is way better then reading a book, because you can do it on you own tempo.

That's how I did it.